# Android App Links and build flavors -- multiple declarations required in assetlinks.json?

Tags: android, json, android-6.0-marshmallow, deep-linking, applinks

I am working on implementing [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) for a project which has multiple build flavors and I am wondering how I should structure my `assetlinks.json` file.

The package names have a `com.android.shared.package.flavor` format, can I just use `"package_name": "com.android.shared.package"` in my `assetlinks.json` declaration? [Or do I have to treat each build flavor as a separate app and follow the process for associating the site with multiple apps in the assetlinks.json file](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#multiple-apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think the answer is it depends on the final use case.

If you expect your users to only ever have one flavor of your app installed (ex. Free vs Premium) then a single link to package is fine.

If you expect your users might install more than one (ex App Skinned for various branding) then you will want link to each flavor individually.  This will allow a user to have multiple flavors installed and the linking should work.